# Fabric8: OSGI bundle jars for openshift and kubernetes java client

Tags: maven, osgi, kubernetes, openshift, fabric8

I am working on integrating fabric8 for my application and need to add fabric8 kubernetes and openshift client as OSGI bundles. I can get them from following maven repositories as JAR archives.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8/openshift-client/2.5.7
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.5.7

And and have to convert them to OSGI bundles to add them to my application since my application is only supporting bundles.
Is there a way to directly get the OSGI bundles of the above jars from maven repository as dependencies without converting them and adding them to a central repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get OSGI bundles, we have to build it manually.
We can make it available but we have to prepare the bundle and there are plenty of tools available,
For reference:

- http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html
- http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

The kubernetes-client ships bundles for all its artifacts. The bundles are available on maven central and you can use them just by using the bundle classifier.

For example:

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.6.2/kubernetes-client-2.6.2-bundle.jar
```